# Reporting Services Database on different version

Tags: ssrs, sql-server-2017, ssrs-2014

Just wondering if anyone has come across this scenario and can provide some advice.

We have a vendor application that only runs on SQL Server Reporting Services 2014. However, all of our other applications support SQL Server 2017.

Can I setup SSRS 2014 on a separate server, but have the database residing on the SQL Server 2017 server?

Cheers
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to provide a follow-up to this in case anyone is looking to do the same thing.

We've been running SSRS 2014 with the database residing on a separate SQL 2017 instance for over three weeks now without any adverse effects.

Do bear in mind that as [HandyD](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/136353/handyd) has stated above, this is not explicitly supported and we're running it in a non-production environment.

Cheers
Phil

Answer (score 0):

According to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/create-a-report-server-database-ssrs-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2014#database-server-version-requirements), you can run a version of SSRS and host the database on lower versions of SQL Server, but there doesn't appear to be explicit support for running the DB on higher versions.